# Select First 3 Domain Only URLs in list of URLs in Python

Tags: python, regex

I'm struggling to think of the logic behind a certain operation.

I have a list of URLs for instance:

```
["https://example1.com", 
"example2.com",
"http://example3.com/subpage",
"http://example4.com/",
"http://example5.com/subpage"]
```

and I need to extract the first 3 results but ONLY if the result is a domain only. If it has a subpage, I want to ignore it.

Any idea how to do this? I guess first thing would be to go through the list and remove anything that is a subpage then just select the first 3.

But what's the best way to decide whether a URL is a domain only or a subpage?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter the list and then use list slicing:

```
import re
d = ['https://example1.com', 'example2.com', 'http://example3.com/subpage', 'http://example4.com/', 'http://example5.com/subpage']
new_d = [i for i in d if re.findall('\.[a-z]{3}$|\.[a-z]{3}/$', i)][:3]
```

Output:

```
['https://example1.com', 'example2.com', 'http://example4.com/']
```

Edit: regex explanation:

`\.`: matches occurrence of `"."`

`[a-z]{3}`: matches three letters after a `"."`

`$`: anchors expression at the very end of the string.

Comment: I'll be honest I don't know what that Regex means but it does work. Thank you very much.

Comment: @JeffreyWinger Glad to help! Please see my recent edit for an explanation of the regex.